# When is $ x(n) = A \cos (\omega_0 n + \phi)\ ,\ n \in \mathbb{Z} $ periodic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I know that sometimes, discrete time sinusoids are not periodic.

But how can you figure that out?

Comment: What are $A, \omega_0, \phi$?

Comment: @Mr.Chip They are real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for anyone wondering, as I found [here](http://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~dkundur/course_info/signals/notes/Kundur_DstTimeSinusoids.pdf), we're looking for the integer period $N\ ,\ N > 0$ such that

$$ \begin{align}
x(n) &= x(n + N)\\
A \cos (\omega n + \phi) &= A \cos (\omega (n + N) + \phi )\\
A \cos (\omega n + \phi + 2\pi k) &= A \cos (\omega n + \phi + \omega N)\\
\therefore\ 2\pi k &= \omega N\\
N &= \frac{2\pi k}{\omega}
\end{align}
$$
, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Notice that there may not exist a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{2\pi k}{\omega}$ is an integer.

Comment: I think you are talking about discrete signal x[n].